# Go build error " go: no matching versions for query "latest" "

Tags: go, testing, build, test-coverage

I'm trying to find the test coverage inside the package but the build fails without any error. There's no error when I tried to find the test coverage for other packages inside the same project. I'm using goland to find the test coverage.When I'm trying to build the package I'm getting the " go: no matching versions for query "latest" " error. Tried restarting the pc, it's not working.
The directory structure is :

> foo-> fooPackage->foo.go

The error message I'm getting

> FAIL  project/utilities/rest/sign
> [build failed]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even though you haven't encountered an error message, it's important to mention what actions / commands you are executing, and what output exactly are you seeing.

Comment: Have edited the question with error

Comment: Are you able to build the package successfully with a normal build command?

Comment: No I'm not able to build this package. But I could build every other package successfully

Comment: Got this error go: finding module for package project/utilities
no matching versions for query "latest"

Comment: It seems like that is your real problem. Have you tried searching for solutions for that error message?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it was not fruitful

Comment: @gokul_santhosh Have you tried cleaning the module cache, ```go clean -modcache``` and retrying after that?

Comment: Yes, I have. That didn't work either

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think your question has enough information right now to answer. You are experiencing a go build error which seems to have various causes, and right now we have almost no information about your project except for a few folder names.

Answer (score 5):

To clean your mod cache:

`go clean -modcache`

You can also fetch a specific version:

`go get -u github.com/author/pkgname@semver (v0.0.0-20180830031419-95f893ade6f2)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to get a private package, but my access token had expired. Generating a new one fixed the issue.